# Wordpress Website Keeps Redirecting to Different Domain

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a wordpress website but it keeps redirecting to a different domain:

Link is [here](http://cura.co.ke/):

I have tried the following:

1. Contacted the hosting and they say it is not hacked or compromised
2. Tried on different computers and browser. On one computer it works fine. 5 other computers and browsers it redirects
3. I have done the scan by wordfence and sucuri and nothing malicious shows up
4. I tried to inspect the element but the redirect is so fast its hard to inspect
5. .htaccess has the following:

The following is the content of the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Please help

Comment: Have you check for redirects in your `.htaccess` file? When did this start happening?

Comment: @lonut yes i have checked the .htaccess file and it has no redirects.

Comment: What the actual domain of your website? Now I see `http://cura.co.ke/`

Comment: the actual domain is cura.co.ke

Comment: Then it's not redirecting to another domain as you said. When I click on the link from your question it goes to `http://cura.co.ke/`

Comment: can you provide us with a page link of your website? not the main page

Comment: @lonut he means the page keeps looping through itself

Comment: @YahyaHHussein, no, he clearly said `I have a wordpress website but it keeps redirecting to a different domain`

Comment: yes sorry, did not pay enough attention, the website is working well from my side, @user38208 can you please mention where your website is redirecting to?

Comment: Check the code, looks like it was hacked.

Comment: @YahyaHHussein one of the link it redirects to is `http://mobi2u.biz/ke/flashlight?offer_id=115&aff_id=45&aff_sub=jKE24TDV017LH010067I0M464026KFWF0TPC15I93fFJ01UN026KF00&aff_sub2=&aff_sub3=&aff_sub4=&aff_sub5=&transaction_id=126661061&carrier=&country=Kenya&city=Mombasa/#`

Comment: @mokiSRB which code looks like its been hacked?

Comment: do you have a website backup? if you do, restore it

Comment: Unfortunately the backup was overridden by the current version

Comment: @user38208 Not this code, php code.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is very late but I'll share my experience to help any one who has this problem.
cause of this issue can be a plugin that you downloaded from outside of wordpress.org or some body has access to your wordpress admin account and you doesn't already close editor.php in appearance tab or hacker has your ftp user and password or ...
to solve this create a full backup first and save it in your computer in case of doing any mistake and then:

1. go to theme directory of your wordpress site and delete all of the unused theme because they are infected already.
2. in active theme edit your functions.php file and delete all extra code inserted by malware. you can search for "wp_vcd" or "wp-tmp" words to find the code.
3. download latest wordpress installation. then delete wp-include and wp-admin folder and all files in public_html except wp-content folder and .htaccess file and wp-config.php file. after that replace deleted files and folder with downloaded wordpress.
4. remove all plugins that you downloaded from known source.
5. finally change all of your passwords like ftp, admin panel, cpanel or direct admin and ... in case if hacker saved your info somewhere.
   hope this little guide can help someone.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18958543)

Comment: @GGO thank's for the advice . i edited the answer know.